# Python Requests Chunk Data

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm trying to scrap a site with python's requests library, but it's chunking my data. The site in question is a bit weird and returns html from a POST and when I read the response, requests prints only 1/5 of the page.
heres the code:

```
import requests
LIST_ITEMS_URL = 'http://www.solicitador.org/vendas/consultas/ListaBens.jsp'

r = requests.post(LIST_ITEMS_URL, 
            data = {
                'iddistrito': 13, 
                'idconcelho': 6, 
                'tipo_bem':1,
                'pageOri': 'PesquisaAvancada.jsp'
            }, headers = {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Length' : '111',
                'Cookie' : 'JSESSIONID=0002K67DUGhI4ioO6eE3oCeKYSQ:-G1B89M',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' : '1'
            }
    )
print r.content
```

Also if when i use a browser API Client, the response size has 31 KBytes, with requests only +- 8192 Bytes

anyone has any idea of whats limiting the response here?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing pagination in your code. Quick glance to the page revealed that, you may get rest of the pages as using `currentPage` parameter in your POST request. `currentPage:1` gets the second page, `currentPage:2` gets the 3rd page so on.

Issues i've found in given example:

- remove cookie & content-length fields from headers.
- remove data.

The post result should be complete.

Comment: thats not it. if i compare with the content returned from an api client like postman. the results are different. the requests library is processing the response and not returning everything

Comment: I don't know about postman's implementation but when you write scraper code, you should mimic the browser behaviour.

Comment: i know. but try the code i posted. the r.content will only display a part of the page. you won't even see the final closing tags

Comment: after all it's something regarding requests itself. it's probably reading the response text and cutting it. please try: requests.get(LIST_ITEMS_URL+'?tipo_bem=1&iddistrito=13&idconcelho=6&pageOri=PesquisaAvancada.jsp').content

Comment: If you suspect requests as reason of the cause (which is highly unlikely), you may try using curl command. I think the http query parameters could be the one to blame.

Comment: fixed, i set a bunch of cookies just like the browser and it worked. the server was messing with me.